# In my JSP page, for ajax multipart form data submit, upload.parseRequest(request) return empty list when image is not uploaded

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, multipartform-data

In **my .java** file,
 whenever file is uploaded and form is submitted through ajax,  **upload.parseRequest(request) return all field properly**,

but whenever a form is submitted without file, **upload.parseRequest(request) return empty list**.

Can anyone please suggest me any solution.

```
if (!isMultipart) {
System.out.println("Inside isMultipart ------------------------->" + imageName);                
} 
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

// Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
factory.setRepository(new File(imagesavingLocation));

FileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
upload.setHeaderEncoding(request.getCharacterEncoding());
List items = null;

items = upload.parseRequest(request);
Iterator iterator = items.iterator ();
```

and my js file appear like this

```
  var form = $('#merchantSignupForm')[0];

    var fd = new FormData(form);


    fd.append('firmname', $("#firmname").val());
    fd.append('firmtype', $("#firmtype").val());
    fd.append('pancard', $("#pancardnumber").val());
    fd.append('vatnumber', $("#vatnumber").val());
  fd.append('filevatnumber',$("input[name='filevatnumber']:checked").val());
    fd.append('contactnumber', $("#contactnumber").val());

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      url: urlCS+"?actionname=CustomerSupportAjaxHandler.setMerchantDetail&firmname="+$("#firmname").val(),
      data: fd,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,

      success: function(data){

          if(typeof data === "object" && data.status == 'success')
            {
                $("#merchantMsg").html("<span class='success_FieldText'>Merchant Sign up sucessfully</span>");
                 $('.realperson-text').click();
                  $(window).scrollTop($('#merchantMsg').offset().top);
                 $("#merchantSignupForm").get(0).reset(); 
            }
            else
            {   
                 $('.realperson-text').click();
                $('#captcha').val('Type the word*');
                $(window).scrollTop($('#merchantMsg').offset().top);
                $("#merchantMsg").html("<span class='errMsg'>  Error occured Please Try again ! </span>");
            }
      },
      error: function() 
        { 
             $('.realperson-text').click();
            $('#captcha').val('Type the word*');
            $(window).scrollTop($('#merchantMsg').offset().top);
            $("#merchantMsg").html("<span class='errMsg'>  Error occured Please Try again !</span>");
        }
    });
```